# Why doesn't window.something throw an error?

Tags: javascript, cordova, ionic-framework

I'm using an AdMob plugin in my Ionic application, and one way, as you can see in [the documentation](https://github.com/floatinghotpot/cordova-admob-pro), to test if the plugin is properly loaded is to do:

```
if(AdMob) {
    ///other config code...
}
```

Now, this works perfectly fine **on a device**. However, it doesn't work **in the browser**; it throws an error in the console log: `AdMob is not defined`.

I have found a solution to test the existence of plugin like this (without throwing an error in the console):

```
if (window.AdMob){...}
```

And I have seen this usage on multiple questions here on StackOverflow. However, I wasn't able to find an explanation to as **why** this doesn't throw an error.

I have a vague reasoning to as why this would be so, but I would really appreciate it if someone experienced could explain it in more detail.

**edit**: I made additional tests like this:

```
var a = "hi";
console.log(a); //shows "hi"
console.log(b); //throws an error that b is not defined

var c = {};
c.b = "hi again";
console.log(c.b); //shows "hi again" as expected

//and now for the grand finale
console.log(c.something);//doesn't throw an error, please explain to me in more detail why?
```

Comment: When you attempt to read an attribute that doesn't exist (x.y), you get the value undefined. When you attempt to read a variable that doesn't exist, you get a reference error. Someone can find the spec text about it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I wasn't able to find an explanation to as why this doesn't throw an error.

In the first example, you're trying to read the value of a completely undefined identifier. In the second example, you're trying to read a property from an object that the object may not have.

Trying to read the value of an undefined identifier is a `ReferenceError`; the JavaScript engine has no idea what that identifer is. In contrast, trying to read the value of a property that the object doesn't have yields the value `undefined`.

It's just how the language is designed, where Brendan Eich drew the line: It's okay to read the value of a non-existant property from an object, but not okay to read the value of an undeclared identifier.

I should point out a third option: `typeof`. You're allowed to provide an undefined identifier as the operand to `typeof`:

```
if (typeof AdMob === "undefined")
```

That won't throw a `ReferenceError` even if `AdMob` is undeclared; instead, `typeof` will yield `"undefined"`. (It will also yield `"undefined'` if `AdMob` is a declared identifier with the value `undefined` in it.)

In a comment on another answer, you said:

> ...it would just indeed help to see the exact official specification which confirms this.

That would be the [ECMAScript specification](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html), specifically [§6.2.3.1](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-getvalue) for throwing a `ReferenceError` on an unresolvable symbol, and [§9.1.8](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-ordinary-object-internal-methods-and-internal-slots-get-p-receiver) for returning `undefined` for a property that doesn't exist. But I should warnin you that the spec, especially this 6th edition spec, is **very** heavy going. :-)

Comment: Awesome, thank you, this is truly an elaborate answer. And thanks for the official reference!